# How can I use a calculated value in a Google Sheets Macro to set the endpoint of an array being calculated in a FormulaArray?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to limit the cells being calculated in a FormulaArray in a Google Sheets Macro. I have a var (count2) set that has a count of all the rows with data for today and yesterday. I want to build a formula array that only considers Row 2 to Row **count2** -> This value will change which is why I would like to keep the variable. I have tried several iterations of directly calling the var in the formula array, but none seem to work. I am adding a sample formula;
`spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=iferror(ArrayFormula(iferror(sum(if(R3C2=R3C2:R& count2 &C2,1,0)),"")),200)');`
I have tried several different methods of calling but I can't seem to get the formula to run correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It needed a `+` instead of `&`... 
So the solution is
`spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=iferror(ArrayFormula(iferror(sum(if(R3C2=R3C2:R'+ count2 +'C2,1,0)),"")),200)');`